# getting an error message with a mysql_connect() statement

Tags: php, xampp, mysql-connect

some comments preceding a mysql_connect statement are telling me to modify the values/variable name to my installation. I'm using xamp and looking in php.ini right now. don't really know where the problem is. please advise. Thanks.

php:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost'; //unlikely to require changing.
$dbname ='publication'; //moify these
$dbuser = 'username'; //variables 
$dbpass = 'password'; //// to your installation
$appname = 'Robot City'; // and preference

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
```

error message:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajaxpagination\testpage.php on line 10
Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looking into php.ini you have to look into your XAMPP documentation.
I am sure it contains database credentials you have to use.

As a wild guess try to use

```
$dbname ='test'; //moify these
$dbuser = 'root'; //variables 
$dbpass = '';
```

But again - **refer to the documentation for the actual values.**

There is also a chance that you entered them yourself upon the process of the XAMPP installation.

Note that I have never seen this application in my life. I am writing only out of the general idea of how most applications work.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with php.ini. You're providing the wrong username/password to mysql, or you've not configured that account properly in mysql.

What does `show grants for username@localhost;` show when you run that in mysql?

Comment: ERROR 1044 (42000): Acess denied for used''@'localhost' to databse 'mysql'.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong username and password. Period!!! Try

```
$dbhost = 'localhost'; //unlikely to require changing.
$dbname ='publication'; //moify these
$dbuser = 'root'; //variables 
$dbpass = ''; //// to your installation
$appname = 'Robot City'; // and preference
```